# How to self-reference a control

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my form I need to be able to click on a control and know that control's name in the code.

Is there a way for a control to know it's own name like a form can?

I'm looking for something like this (except this will give the form's name):

```
private sub someControl_click()
    msgbox Me.Name  'tell user the name of the control (= someControl)
end sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the control's `.Name` from `Screen.ActiveControl`.

```vb
Private Sub someControl_click()
    MsgBox Screen.ActiveControl.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: Doh!  I forgot about that!  Thanks for answering, Hans.